# How do I fix my initramfs for booting linux kernel image on qemu?

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, qemu, initramfs, busybox

I am using an M2 mac. I built the linux kernel in a aarch64v8/ubuntu docker container. Here's the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  dev:
    image: arm64v8/ubuntu
    platform: linux/arm64
    volumes:
      - .:/root/myfolder
    working_dir: /root
    #cpus: 
    network_mode: host
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
```

I downloaded linux-5.10.209 and built the kernel. It worked. I downloaded busybox-1.36.1, and built it. It worked too.

Here is my rootfs:

```
(base) varunnawathey@Varuns-MacBook-Pro rootfs % ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 95 varunnawathey  staff  3040 Feb  3 02:58 bin
drwxr-xr-x   6 varunnawathey  staff   192 Feb  3 03:09 dev
drwxr-xr-x   2 varunnawathey  staff    64 Feb  3 03:03 etc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 varunnawathey  staff    11 Feb  3 03:04 init -> bin/busybox
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 varunnawathey  staff    11 Feb  3 02:58 linuxrc -> bin/busybox
drwxr-xr-x   2 varunnawathey  staff    64 Feb  3 03:03 proc
drwxr-xr-x@ 74 varunnawathey  staff  2368 Feb  3 02:58 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 varunnawathey  staff    64 Feb  3 03:03 sys
drwxr-xr-x@  4 varunnawathey  staff   128 Feb  3 02:55 usr
(base) varunnawathey@Varuns-MacBook-Pro rootfs % ls -l dev
total 0
crw-rw----  1 root  staff  0x1000001 Feb  3 03:06 mem
crw-rw----  1 root  staff  0x1000001 Feb  3 03:07 ttyS2
crw-rw----  1 root  staff  0x1000001 Feb  3 03:07 ttyS3
crw-rw----  1 root  staff  0x1000001 Feb  3 03:07 ttyS4
```

I ran this:

```
sudo find .  -print0 | cpio --null -ov --format=newc | gzip -9 > ../rootfs.cpio.gz
```

I got a wall of text, but I think something went wrong here:

```
./sbin/tunctl
./sbin/mkdosfs
./sbin/blkid
./etc
./sys
./linuxrc
./dev
cpio: Couldn't list extended attributes
./dev/ttyS4
cpio: Couldn't list extended attributes
./dev/ttyS3
cpio: Couldn't list extended attributes
./dev/ttyS2
cpio: Couldn't list extended attributes
./dev/mem
4302 blocks
```

I tried making a rootfs, but it did not work. That's where I am stuck. There were some steps that required mknod and it was not allowed in the docker container.

I am lost on what to do here. I don't know how I should go about making the initramfs if I have to run mknod through the host instead of in the docker container.

This just hangs:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -m 256M -kernel linux-5.10.209/arch/arm64/boot/Image -initrd rootfs.cpio.gz -append "root=/dev/mem" -nographic
```

Should I have made the docker container priveleged? How would I even do that?

Or am I missing something needed to boot the kernel with qemu?